# bootstrap 3 grid issue - small columns overriding medium or larger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I’m having an issue with the bootstrap grid. I’m trying to create (3) four column divs on medium screens, on small screens I’m trying to create six column divs that are offset 3 columns so they are centered. and on extra small screens twelve columns. Seems like something I’ve done a million times… but on medium or larger they are stacking using the .sm class… not sure what’s happening?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4">col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4</div><!-- close col -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4">col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4</div><!-- close col -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4">col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4</div><!-- close col -->
</div><!-- close row -->
```

here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/aaron4osu/pen/Powpezo

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit confusing, but I'll try to help.

Your first issue is using .col-offset- improperly which is preventing your columns from operating correctly (read more about offsetting here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-offsetting)

Your second issue is using .col-sm-6 three times.

With the Bootstrap grid system, your column classes must always equal 12 (because it's a 12 column grid). Having .col-sm-6 three times equals 18 (not 12) so Bootstrap will push your 3rd .col-sm-6 column underneath the others.

Also, always wrap a .container or .container-fluid around your .row or you're going to run into problems later like horizontal scrolling.

And finally, to center your divs on sm and xs, just use .col-xs-12 and then your divs will be centered (and 100% width) until they reach the .col-md- breakpoint, and then they will be .col-md-4 (3 columns, because 4 goes into 12 three times):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">Column 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```